# Google Sheets - How to move every single row downwards based on a cell's status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sorry if the title is confusing.
Basically, I'm trying to make a log register
[screenshot of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2aIE.png)
I want it so each time I write something on the empty "Log" column in row 3, the ID, Date and Hour are automatically filled and the entire row is moved downwards, leaving an empty one in row 3 again for me to fill when i want.

I don't know how it would be possible to make this as I don't really know to program or even use Google Sheets that well, so I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires an onEdit trigger and cannot be run from script editor or a menu.  Copy it into the Script editor and then editor the appropriate column to trigger the script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Log" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    e.source.toast("Gate2");
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(e.range.offset(-1,-3).getValue() + 1);
    e.range.offset(0, -2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
  } 
  if(sh.getName() == "Log" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1')
    e.range.offset(0, -3).setValue(1);
    e.range.offset(0, -2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Drop Down one row:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Log" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1')
    e.range.offset(0, -3).setValue(e.range.offset(1,-3).getValue() + 1);
    e.range.offset(0, -2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
    sh.insertRowBefore(2);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]